# Mysql crashed showing following errors. Is this a hack?

Tags: mysql, hacking

```
2015-05-17 14:50:38 1896 [Warning] Host name 'hn.kd.ny.adsl' could not be resolved: No such host is known. 
2015-05-18 00:11:23 1896 [Warning] IP address '222.186.21.38' could not be resolved: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 
2015-05-18 12:12:57 1896 [Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to '216.99.158.181'.
2015-05-18 12:12:57 1896 [Note] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' has the following IP addresses:
2015-05-18 12:12:57 1896 [Note]  - 199.15.112.8
2015-05-18 15:12:41 1896 [Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to '216.99.158.158'.
2015-05-18 15:12:41 1896 [Note] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' has the following IP addresses:
2015-05-18 15:12:41 1896 [Note]  - 199.15.112.8
2015-05-19 16:27:21 1896 [Warning] Host name 'hn.kd.ny.adsl' could not be resolved: No such host is known.
```

Comment: Is your MySQL installation open to the public internet?

Comment: No, it is not connected to public.

Comment: Why are what look like public IPs/hostnames connecting then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

These two variables are not **global** so need to `service mysql restart` after that

If you want to block all connections to port 3306 (MySQL) and allow only those you want

```
$ iptables -N mysql
$ iptables -A mysql --src 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A mysql -j DROP
$ iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j mysql
```

where 1.1.1.1 is the IP address you want to add in **whitelist**

Comment: Will try this and observe for few days.! Thank you!

Comment: @PavanKumarN If this fixes it, you have a serious security issue that your MySQL server is publicly accessible.